Load unpacked extention error:content_security_policy.extension_pages' insecure csp value in directive 'script-src'
Sorry for bad english.
I want install extention . Its sbc silver for fifa fc 24 web app .
Another user havnt my problem .
Error: content_security_policy.extension_pages' insecure csp value in directive 'script-src' manifist..
I have this error When i load unpacked it in extention menu.
What ? I need help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
